# When conditions in a if statement are met inside a for loop, how can I print one result?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, for-loop, return, output

Basically I have the following code. The problem is that I only want to have "Pass" printed once if both conditions in the if statement are met. The int 'res' is an average of all 6 elements in the parts array. Therefore, all "parts" must have a value of at least 40 and the average of these parts, known as "res", must also be above 40. At the moment the code obviously outputs Pass for each of the 6 elements of the "parts" array if they are over 40. I want this to just however output Pass once if all six elements of the "parts" array and "res" are over or equil to 40.

Any help will be gratefully appreciated!

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {  
            if (res >= 40 && parts[i] >= 40)
            {
              System.out.println("Pass");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things:

1) You look like you're just checking for a negative case. If you find any values that are less than 40 you want to `break` and not print "Pass". If each element is over 40 and res is over 40 you want to continue until you either find one that isn't or finish through the list. If you get through the whole list and none failed you know you can print "Pass".

2) res isn't changing in your loop as you supplied it. If you are changing it in the loop and this is just example code that's fine. But if you're not you should really just check it once outside of the loop.

```
boolean print = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{  
    if (res < 40 | parts[i] < 40)
    {
      print = false;
      break;
    }
}
if(print)
 System.out.println("Pass");
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I'm quite new to Java and miss out simple things like this. Thanks very much for the help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you would want to put

```
break;
```

after the println

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{  
    if (res >= 40 && parts[i] >= 40)
    {
      System.out.println("Pass");
      break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `break;` statement for step out of your loop after you print to the console.

A `break` is used to step out of any kind of loop.

```
while(true){
    //do stuff
    if(condition){
        break;
    }
}
```